# How can i use the AND Operator in Laravel in my query

Tags: sql, laravel

How do I get this syntax in Laravel?

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn = 'A' 
AND myColumn = 'B';
```

I know this syntax in Laravel:

```
DB::table('myTable')->where('myColumn', 'A');
```

And I tried something like this:

```
DB::table('myTable')->where('myColumn', 'A' AND 'B');
```

or

```
DB::table('myTable')->where('myColumn', 'A' AND 'myColumn' 'B');
```

but nothing works

So how can I use the AND operator in Laravel?
Or is this not possible?

Thank You!

I got it now:

```
if(!empty($request->get('typ'))){
     $angebots->whereIn('typ', [$typ, 'Jeden']);
    }
```

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.  Show input and output.

Comment: your question is quite confusing , please add exact name for  `myColumn` ?

Comment: Instead of `!empty($request->get('typ')` try to use `$request->has('typ')`

Comment: Your current query makes no sense.  Please add sample data to your question which explains it.  Sample input and output usually works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereIn`. At your case it have to work.

```
DB::table('myTable')->whereIn('myColumn', ['A', 'B'])
```

And if you are going to use `where`

```
DB::table('myTable')
        ->where('myColumn', 'A')
        ->orWhere('myColumn', 'B');
```

Comment: You have a right, but query in question have two `where`

Comment: just to mention here , Both code are not same, wetting two `where` function are to apply `AND`  and using `whereIn` is for `OR`

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
 DB::table('myTable')->where('myColumn_1', 'A')->where('myColumn_1' 'B')->get();
```

If values are multiple and column name is same then use **whereIn()**

```
 DB::table('myTable')->whereIn('myColumn', ['A','B'])->get(); //pass array of data
```

Comment: you can use whereIn method of laravel

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple `where` conditions, automatically it will take as `AND` operator.

```
DB::table('myTable')->where('myColumn', 'A')->where('myColumn','B')->get();
```

Comment: How can a given column in a single record have two different values at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

**How same column have two column**, I guess you should use `OR` here not `AND`

and for this laravel have `whereIn` function

```
DB::table('myTable')->whereIn('myColumn', ['A','B']);
```

Comment: no i have more values in my column :) so AND is right here :)

Comment: please share your columns value sample ?

Comment: is your `myColumn` different ?

Comment: if(!empty($request->get('typ'))){
         $angebots->whereIn('typ', [$typ, 'Jeden']);
        }

Comment: @MonaMuhr : if `whereIn` worked for you then you were needed `OR` not `AND`